# How to avoid this in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a function that looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sal
    (dep_id IN departments.department_id%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_sal employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(salary) INTO v_sal FROM Employees
    WHERE department_id = dep_id;
    RETURN v_sal;
END;
```

And I get an error that says

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(salary) INTO v_sal FROM Employees
    WHERE department_id = dep_id;
    RETURN v_sal;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 27:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DEP_ID": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I got an example function from Oracle to see if it works but the same error appears.

Comment: As the message says, this is a **compilation error**.  We cannot reproduce it without the tables you're using. All we can say is, there is a discrepancy between the objects in your schema and the identifiers you reference in your code: you need to compare the two and spot where you've made a bloomer.

Comment: If you were using SQL Developer, i suggest you to rephrase your question title to reflect that, like 'Why i'm getting this error when executing this statement with SQL Developer ?"

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sal (dep_id IN departments.department_id%TYPE)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     v_sal  employees.salary%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT AVG (salary)
  7       INTO v_sal
  8       FROM Employees
  9      WHERE department_id = dep_id;
 10
 11     RETURN v_sal;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select get_sal(10) from dual;

GET_SAL(10)
-----------


SQL>
```

as long as schema you're connected to contains `DEPARTMENTS` and `EMPLOYEES` tables with columns mentioned in that code. If you do not, then yes - expect errors.

Comment: If it was on the wrong schema/database, i guess it would have been the 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' kind. In this case, i suspect more wrong file format (bad LF terminators, bad encoding,  Alt_160 in spacing, etc.).

Comment: I didn't say that *table was missing* (ORA-00942), but that table(s) don't contain columns referenced in that code (ORA-00904), @Zilog80. Cool nickname, BTW.

Comment: As "dep_id"  is the input parameter from the function, it seems that the parser didn't take dep_id at line 9 as an input parameter. I feel that if it comes from a not existing department_id field in table departments or no table/synonym for departments, it would have raise a function def error (PLS-00201: identifier 'DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID' must be declared or PLS-00302: component 'DEPARTMENT_ID' must be declared).

Comment: Right; we're mostly guessing as the OP didn't post tables' description. Tf they choose to do so, we'll be somewhat smarter :)

Comment: Another possibility is the usage of very old sql/sqlplus client, the ones sometimes shipped  with old versions of tools like Oracle forms.@Jonny Discoiulde, could you give us the sql client  version ? (the one showed at start of sqlplus)

Comment: Version is 20.4.0

Comment: @JonnyDiscoiulde I guess that means you're using SQl Developer as a client. Then i guess  your problem is how you use Sql Developer to compile your SQL statement on the database. I'll make an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using Sql Developer 20.4.0 as your SQL client, i guess the problem comes from the way you're compiling your SQL statement within this SQL client.

With SQL Developer, there is two ways to compile a SQL statement/execute a query. Selecting it in the editor and then click the green play button on the left as shown in the image below. The second way is to have only your statements in the editor and use the execute script button which is the second button to the right of the green play button. This one will execute all the statements in the editor.

I guess your error come from the use of the green play button while your cursor in the editor is on the statement but the statement is not fully selected or partially selected.

You can make SQL Developer complies with the behavior of Toad or have a custom behavior in this way in the SQL Developer options.

[image]